# How do i write this function in Haskell

Tags: csv, haskell

I am required to do a haskell project which takes a csv and calculate the average for each day from it.

Below is the code I have done so far

```
main :: IO ()
main = someFunc

rawData :: IO [[[Char]]]
rawData = readFile "dataexport.csv" >>= 
    return . lines >>=
        return . drop 10 >>=
            return . map (K.splitOneOf "T,")
```

Sample data :

location,Kuala Lumpur
lat,2.99990
lon,101.71875
asl,130.207
variable,Temperature
unit,°C
level,2 m elevation corrected
resolution,hourly
aggregation,None
timestamp,Kuala Lumpur Temperature [2 m elevation corrected]
20200511T0000,25.952345
20200511T0100,25.802345
20200511T0200,25.732346
20200511T0300,25.632345
20200511T0400,25.562346
20200511T0500,25.492346
20200511T0600,25.372345
20200511T0700,25.222345
20200511T0800,26.492346
20200511T0900,27.092346
20200511T1000,27.502346
20200511T1100,28.112345
20200511T1200,28.382345
20200511T1300,28.582346
20200511T1400,29.142345
20200511T1500,29.072346
20200511T1600,28.892345
20200511T1700,28.632345
20200511T1800,28.542345
20200511T1900,28.152346
20200511T2000,27.512346
20200511T2100,27.212345
20200511T2200,26.832346
20200511T2300,26.542345
20200512T0000,26.282345
20200512T0100,25.962345
20200512T0200,25.682346
20200512T0300,25.492346
20200512T0400,25.372345
20200512T0500,25.242346
20200512T0600,25.082346
20200512T0700,24.822346
20200512T0800,26.202345
20200512T0900,28.192345
20200512T1000,29.152346
20200512T1100,30.122345
20200512T1200,29.362345
20200512T1300,29.182346
20200512T1400,29.072346
20200512T1500,28.902346
20200512T1600,28.772346
20200512T1700,28.582346
20200512T1800,28.922346
20200512T1900,28.322346
20200512T2000,27.352346
20200512T2100,27.122345
20200512T2200,26.872345
20200512T2300,26.572346

Comment: What do you expect your code to do? What happens instead?

Comment: It would be helpful to separate the `IO` code from the parsing code, then split the parsing code into separate functions for each step. Then you can incrementally test the operations going from CSV to lists of numbers you can perform computations on.